# Second moment conditional multivariate gaussian distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

What is the second moment of the conditional distribution of one multivariate normal variable given another multivariate normal variable? I know the formula for the second central moment (the variance), but the second moment is hard to find online.

$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} xx'f(x\vert y)dx$$

In my case, the marginal and conditional means and variances are known.

Comment: You know the conditional mean and variance, right?

Comment: Yes indeed, and also the marginal mean and variance

Comment: There is an equation relating mean, variance, and second moment. To jog your memory, you’ve probably seen it using expected value notation.

Comment: You say it's a multivariate normal, but then integrate on the real line. Could you clarify?

Comment: So, what I'm asking is if the following is implied:$$E[\mathbf x|\mathbf Y]=\mathbf{\mu_x}+\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}(\mathbf{Y-\mu_Y})$$

$$\text{Var}[\mathbf x|\mathbf Y]=\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,x}}-\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,x}}$$

Comment: I'm integrating over a vector, so I'm writing multiple integrals as one

Comment: Yes, those formula's are indeed implied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two multivariate normal vectors $\mathbf{x}\sim\mathcal N(\mathbf{\mu_x},\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,x}})$ and $\mathbf{Y}\sim\mathcal N(\mathbf{\mu_Y},\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}})$ we have that, given their covariance $\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}$:

$$E[\mathbf x|\mathbf Y]=\mathbf{\mu_x}+\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}(\mathbf{Y-\mu_Y})$$

$$\text{Var}[\mathbf x|\mathbf Y]=\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,x}}-\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,x}}$$

But the covariance is given in terms of the second moment:

$$\text{Var}[\mathbf x|\mathbf Y]=E[\mathbf {xx}^T|\mathbf Y]-E[\mathbf x|\mathbf Y]E[\mathbf {x}^T|\mathbf Y]$$

So

$$E[\mathbf {xx}^T|\mathbf Y] = \text{Var}[\mathbf x|\mathbf Y] + E[\mathbf x|\mathbf Y]E[\mathbf {x}^T|\mathbf Y]\\
=\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,x}}-\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,x}}+
(\mathbf{\mu_x}+\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}(\mathbf{Y-\mu_Y}))
(\mathbf{\mu_x}+\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}(\mathbf{Y-\mu_Y}))^T$$

---

I haven't checked, but it seems this all stems from the simple fact that:

$$\mathbf x=\mathbf{\mu_x}+\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}(\mathbf{Y-\mu_Y})+\mathbf e\\
E[\mathbf {xx}^T|\mathbf Y]=(\mathbf{\mu_x}+\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}(\mathbf{Y-\mu_Y}))(\mathbf{\mu_x}+\Sigma_{\mathbf{x,Y}}\Sigma_{\mathbf{Y,Y}}^{-1}(\mathbf{Y-\mu_Y}))^T+E[\mathbf {ee}^T|\mathbf Y]
$$

So we could've started directly here, and then $E[\mathbf {ee}^T|\mathbf Y] = \text{Var}[\mathbf x|\mathbf Y]$.